# Getting internal server error after updating server config via WHM?

Tags: apache-2.2, configuration

I am running a server with CentOS and Apache2. I use Web Host Manager (WHM) for management.

I was changing Apache configuration from WHM. I updated the max child processes from 150 to 100 and saved and restarted the server. Now I keep getting internal server error everywhere on my server.

I also made an automatic memory configuration which set each process memory limit to 64MB.

In my error log I can see following unusual errors after update:

```
[Fri Jun 29 16:39:18 2012] [error] [client 41.239.56.253] /usr/bin/php: error while loading shared libraries: libmysqlclient.so.16: failed to map segment from shared object: Cannot allocate memory, referer: http://apps.facebook.com/froiden-male-female/...

[Fri Jun 29 16:45:50 2012] [error] [client 122.164.189.14] Premature end of script headers: index.php, referer: http://apps.facebook.com/froiden-male-female/
```

Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It might be not enough memory for the library. Open your `/usr/local/apache/conf/httpd.conf` and remove the following lines from there:

```
RLimitMEM 651048618
RLimitCPU 240
```

They are usually on the top of the file. Then restart your web server:

```
/etc/init.d/httpd restart
```

Comment: I found that solution before your posted. But anyway thanks!!! :)